# How to extend a test class of dependent module

Tags: 6

I am creating a module with dependency on another contrib module. When I am trying to extend the test class in dependent module, it works fine locally(using test UI). However when I try to test my new module in qa.drupal.org it throws error saying that the  'Class not found' as the dependency module is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use function [module_load_include](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_load_include/6) to include file in your module. Class not found because main class not include in your case.

Comment: Well, include doesn't work as qa.d.o does not install the module. It just checkout my repo and find .test file and run tests using run-test.sh

Comment: This doesn't work in Drupal 10. `module_load_include()` does not exist at that point. That function is also deprecated and replaced with `\Drupal::moduleHandler()->loadInclude()`. This does not work either; it raises `PHPUnit\TextUI\RuntimeException: \Drupal::$container is not initialized yet. \Drupal::setContainer() must be called with a real container.`